# Failing to Split String

Tags: python

I am having a stupid problem where there are blank items in the list. There are if statements in it to attempt to offset it, but even with them, the output contains empty parts.

I have been playing around with string.split() a lot and found that what it takes is really specific, and each time i attempt to make it work, it fails. What's going wrong?

```
a = 'Beautiful, is==; better*than\nugly'
import re

a = re.split(',|\s|=|;|\*|\n| ',a)

for x in a:
    if x == '\n':
        a.remove(x)
    elif x == ' ':
        a.remove(x)
    elif x == '':
        a.remove(x)

print(a)
print("REE")
```

I want the outcome to only be:
['Beautiful', 'is', 'better', 'than', 'ugly']

But the actual outcome is:
['Beautiful', '', 'is', '', '', '', 'better', 'than', 'ugly']

Comment: "==;" is getting split 3 times

Comment: It should be excluded like * and /n, shouldn't it? And even then, wouldn't the for statement remove those empty spots?

Comment: `a = re.split('\W+', a)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to split on groups of any number of your delimiter characters.  The way you're doing it now, you're splitting on only one at a time.  This gives you what you want:

```
import re

a = 'Beautiful, is==; better*than\nugly'

a = re.split(r'[,\s=;*\n]+',a)

print(a)
```

Result:

```
['Beautiful', 'is', 'better', 'than', 'ugly']
```

If you want to split on all non-alphanumeric characters, you can use this expression instead:

```
a = re.split(r'[^\w]+',a)
```